# train_test_split errors with two csv files

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, testing, nlp

I am working with 2 csv files and I want to compares values from both using the train_test_split function.

My code is the following:

```
X = np.append(y1[:100])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y1)
```

I know that X and y1 are not of the same length and I was trying to fix this error:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4840242, 44898]

However, with the first line I am currently getting this error:

> File "<**array_function** internals>", line 179, in append
> TypeError: _append_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'

How would I be able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [numpy append function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) wrong. The function expects an array to append to. You are just giving it values, but not the array that these values are supposed to be appended on (or the other way around, you are giving the array, but not the values). If the first 100 entries in y are supposed to be your X, simply writing `X = y[:100]` will suffice.